# Export each table row to JSON file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called LineItems like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LineItems] 
(
    [Id]        BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [StartDate] DATETIME2(7) NULL,
    [EndDate]   DATETIME2(7) NULL,
    [Status]    TINYINT DEFAULT (CONVERT([tinyint], (0))) NOT NULL,
);
```

I need to export each row in this table to a single JSON file ({id}.json). I have tried the `FOR JSON` clause supported by SQL Server([Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)).

Query

```sql
SELECT TOP 3   
    Id,  
    [Name],  
    StartDate,  
    EndDate,
    [Status]
FROM 
    [dbo].[LineItems]  
FOR JSON PATH
```

Result

```json
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "line item 1",
    "StartDate": "2021-01-19T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-01-22T00:00:00",
    "Status": 0
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "line item 2",
    "StartDate": "2021-02-02T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-02-03T00:00:00",
    "Status": 1
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "line item 3",
    "StartDate": "2021-02-21T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-02-23T00:00:00",
    "Status": 0
}]
```

The problem is that The output is multiple rows in one file. I couldn't find a method to get a single JSON file for each row.
**Required result files sample is:**

1.json

```json
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "line item 1",
    "StartDate": "2021-01-19T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-01-22T00:00:00",
    "Status": 0
}
```

2.json

```json
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "line item 2",
    "StartDate": "2021-02-02T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-02-03T00:00:00",
    "Status": 1
}
```

3.json

```json
{
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "line item 3",
    "StartDate": "2021-02-21T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2021-02-23T00:00:00",
    "Status": 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the current query so as to be nested within `OPENJSON` function such as

```
SELECT CONCAT(JSON_VALUE([value],'$.Id'),'.JSON') AS [file], [value] 
  FROM OPENJSON(
                (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [dbo].[LineItems] FOR JSON PATH)
                )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a410d3e62e26f8c902a34d4751db8a64)</kbd>

where `JSON_VALUE([value],'$.Id')` is used to extract the `Id` value if matters it to select seperately to get the name of the related file.

Answer (score 1):

File names and their desired content

```
select top(3) cast(row_number() over(order by id) as varchar(10)) + '.JSON' file_name, t.j
from [dbo].[LineItems]    
cross apply (
   select Id,  
          [Name],  
          StartDate,  
          EndDate,
          [Status]
   for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) t(j);
```